# Line break issue when configuring "send on behalf of"

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, ems

I have a script to set *send on behalf of* permissions in Exchange Management Shell, but when you try and use it it fails because the output of the first part is too long and truncates over 2 lines.

First thing we do is build our array from lists of people and put them into some variables to pass:

```
function Add-Send ($mailbox, $target) {
    #"Granting send on behalf for $mailbox to $target"
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{ Add = $target }
}
```

We pass a long list as the `$target` and the maibox name is `$mailbox` and if we output the text we get:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "mr.jeff" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{ Add = "alan.alanson", "bob.bobson", "steve.stevenson" }
```

All fine and good but if there are more than `N` characters in the output then we get a line break:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "mr.jeff" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{ Add = "alan.alanson", "bob.bobson", "steve.stevenson", ...
..., "cath.cathdotir" }
```

When you run this script with the overlength output, then command fails as the output which should be passed to the CLI is passed over more than one line. PowerShell treats each line as a separate command, and they obviously fail with bad syntax.

Our string is output from an array that we build like this:

```
function Send-Array ($mailbox) {
    $target = Get-Content ".\list\dpt1.txt"
    $target += Get-Content ".\list\$mailbox.txt"
    $target += Get-Content ".\list\dpt2.txt"
    $target = $target | Select-Object -Unique
    $separator = '", "'
    $target= $target -replace '^|$','"' -join ','
    Add-Send $mailbox $target
}
```

This gives us an array with strings that look like:

```
"alan.alanson", "bob.bobson", "steve.stevenson"
```

From here I am at a loss any ideas would be much appreciated.

The obvious solution would be to pass the names one at a time, but due to a gotcha with Exchange Server every time you set *send on behalf of* permissions with PowerShell it wipes the existing permissions, so you only end up with he last person granted permissions being able to send on behalf of.

Comment: No, the obvious solution would be to not write the output from Add-Send to the screen - either assign it directly to a variable, or execute it right there and then

Comment: The text output is only for our testing, usually its executed directly. I have amended the original post to better reflect that.

Comment: Hi VPope, have you checked this ? http://mandie.net/2013/01/23/modifying-grantsendonbehalfto-without-tears/ It seems to address the specific issue you encounter when trying to add a new permission (and keep the existing ones).

Comment: Interesting use of distribution groups I will look into that as an option now

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://mandie.net/2013/01/23/modifying-grantsendonbehalfto-without-tears/) for help with your underlying issue.

Very basically, you will have to:

- get the `DistinguishedName` of the user you need to add
- store the current value of `GrantSendOnBehalfTo` in a variable
- append the new user's distinguished name to the list
- replace `GrantSendOnBehalfTo` with the new list

Afterwards you should not need to pass endless strings to the EMS (I hope so).